# Laravel custom command and Scheduler: how to know where the error stands

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I'm developing a blog platform with Laravel 5.6 and posts' publication can be scheduled.
To achieve it, I:

1. Created the `post:publish {id}` command through `PostPublish` class, placed in `Console/Commands` folder.
2. Based on what the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#registering-commands) says, the command is automatically loaded because in `Console/Commands`, so I didn't registered into the `$commands` property in `Console/Kernel.php` (if I run `php artisan list`, `post:publish` is indeed listed).
3. Whenever a user schedules a post, the post is inserted into the `blog_posts` table classified as `scheduled` and a new record is added into `tasks` table (`id`, `command`, `cron`). e.g. `4`, `post:publish 56`, `17 11 18 9 2`.
4. I added the Laravel's Scheduler Cron entry on the server to run every minute, replacing `>> /dev/null 2>&1` with the path of the log file: `* * * * *   /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/qs266dg7/public_html && php artisan schedule:run >> /home/qs266dg7/public_html/app/Console/cron.log`
5. To set the cronjob dynamically, I decided to use [this solution](https://unnikked.ga/how-to-schedule-user-generated-cron-jobs-in-laravel-8a1e0400bb10) at the moment (although I don't think is the most efficient one). So, in the `schedule()` method inside the `Kernel{}` class I get all the entries of `tasks` table, running the `command()` method per each one.

---

**The problem**: the post's status doesn't change as it's stated in `handle()` method of the `PostPublish` class and I don't know how to understand where the problem stands, since everything is done automatically on the server.
Laravel's `appendOutputTo()` didn't produce any output in `cron.log`, that's why I set `>> /home/qs266dg7/public_html/app/Console/cron.log`. What the log file now contains is a long list of:

```
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.20
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.
```

Where does the problem lie? In the command? In the execution of it? In the cron? How can I know it?

---

*app/Console/Commands/* ***PostPublish.php***

```
class PostPublish extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'post:publish {id}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Publish posts that have been scheduled';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $post = BlogPost::find($this->argument('id'));
        $post->status = "published";
        $post->published_at = $post->scheduled_at;
        $post->scheduled_at = null;
        return $post->save();
    }
}
```

*app/Console/* ***Kernel.php***

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $tasks = Task::all();
        foreach ($tasks as $task) {
            $schedule->command($task->command)
                ->cron($task->cron)
                ->appendOutputTo('/home/qs266dg7/public_html/storage/app/Console/cron.log');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: `/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/qs266dg7/public_html && php artisan schedule:run` That looks strange, what's that `public_html` folder part doing there? Shouldn't this be `/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/qs266dg7/public_html/artisan schedule:run` ?

Comment: @kerbholz `public_html` is the folder where Laravel is installed (i.e. where artisan command can be run). Do you think that `/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php` is strange? Because I'm not a cron expert and I copied that first part from other apps on the server (e.g. Magento) that I know are running cron jobs correctly, but I don't really know what it addresses.

Comment: No, that `public_html && artisan` part looks strange. Your command should be `/path/to/php /path/to/artisan schedule:run`. If `php` is alredy in your PATH, you could do `php /path/to/artisan schedule:run`. Never seen `/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php` but if that works for other cronjobs, fine.

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks for the clarification of the first part. My question is: shouldn't I have to specify `php artisan schedule:run` (or, at least, `artisan schedule:run`) to run the artisan command, like when I manually run artisan commands?

Comment: Yes, see my first comment: `/opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/qs266dg7/public_html/artisan schedule:run` First part is where your `php` executable is located, second part is where `artisan` is located (your project folder, including the `artisan` command). Third part is `schedule:run`.

Comment: @kerbholz Sorry, I think I didn't express myself clearly and I missed a part. After your comment I run `which php` on the server that returned `/usr/bin/php`, so now I'm using that path to address php. What I meant is: shouldn't I use something like: `/usr/local/bin/php /home/qs266dg7/public_html artisan schedule:run`? Otherwise, even if I specified the folder as the second paramenter, how can the server know that the command I want to run is an `artisan` command (and not a nonexistent php command)? This is maybe a stupid question, but it's the first time I use cron jobs.

Comment: ;) You're right. I already had that in my code in the first comment: `/home/qs266dg7/public_html/artisan`.

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks for your patience :) I wasn't addressing to `project-folder/artisan` continuing writing `artisan` in front of the command, that's why it didn't work. You definitely solved my problem!

Comment: No problem, glad it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by creating the log

```
use Log;

class PostPublish extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'post:publish {id}';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Publish posts that have been scheduled';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
     try{
            $post = BlogPost::find($this->argument('id'));
            $post->status = "published";
            $post->published_at = $post->scheduled_at;
            $post->scheduled_at = null;
            return $post->save();

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::alert($e);
        }
}
```

}

you can check your log in this file

```
storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Comment: First, thanks for the tip of using `Log` façade. I used `try...catch` plus `Log::info()` as first line in `handle()` and `schedule()` methods, but nothing new is written in `laravel.log`. I guess that Laravel stops even before executing the `schedule()` method.

Comment: @Brigo what version of laravel you are using.

Comment: Although is thank to @kerbholz that I solved this specific problem, since: he just commented, your answer perfectly answers the question _"how to know where the error stands"_ and discovering `Log` façade will be extremely helpful to me, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one :)